# Intent to call playlist editing of Android's default Music app

Tags: android

I'm writing a music app, and want to ask if there's a standard to edit playlist.
Though each manufacture customizes its own default Music app, is there an intent to call up most of them?
If so I guess it will have action EDIT, but I don't know how to write the Data and Type.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is 
No

The long answer is, It might be possible if you create and edit you own playlists in the app and it saves it to the directory for the music application (say /sdcard/music/playlist) then forcing the [mediascanner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) to rescan, which should repopulate the media database.

On editing a playlist, everyone accepts [M3U](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U#Example) which is **literally** a text file.

But again the problem is that not all music players will check that directory at runtime (but most music apps use the media directory created by media scanner so this shouldn't be a issue)

Comment: note, you are making/editing your own playlist, not using other applications to edit playlists.